# I'd like to upload photos anonymously

Tags: anonymity, image

my goal is to upload photos such that I preserve anonymity (not so concerned about WHAT is being uploaded, but trying to conceal WHO is doing so).

I came up with the idea of taking a screenshot of the photo on my computer, pasting it in MS Paint, then saving this as a PNG. Then upload the PNG onto Postimage.

Could someone point out holes in this technique? Is there a way someone could figure out who I am?

Comment: *Why* do you think that process would be helpful? Is your goal simply to remove the metadata on the photo?

Comment: I removed the VPN part of your process because that doesn't appear to be relevant to the picture. And VPNs aren't necessarily anonymous (that's a completely separate discussion).

Comment: Yeah i want to make sure this can't be traced back to me, and thought this was the best way to avoid metadata. I know metadata terminal tools exist, but this was i don't create any in the final photo.

Comment: The VPN is in case the photo hosting site is ever compromised and logs IP addresses.

Comment: You can just wipe the EXIF data... that's way more efficient and less trouble.

Comment: My understanding is that using Paint i can avoid generating EXIF data in the first place, rather than relying on an EXIF removal tool.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that different vendors use different JPEG compression settings, so that could be enough to deduce your camera OEM (using JPEG compression artifacts) or probably even the period the camera was made because OEMs may change/improve compression settings over time.

To be extra sure this information cannot be sniffed out you could shrink images by any number just not 2 or 4 (due to 8x8 blocks), 3 would be fine and then upscale them using e.g. Lanczos.

> I came up with the idea of taking a screenshot of the photo on my computer, pasting it in MS Paint, then saving this as a PNG.

This is wholly unnecessary and sounds like a chore. You could e.g. simply use IrfanView and shrink them as I said earlier, upscale them and save them as BMPs/PNGs using built-in batch conversion. For good measure you could apply some random effects.

There's still a minor possibility of tracing images. In the past various color [laser] printer vendors added watermarks to images. I can imagine camera vendors doing the same but I don't have proofs of that.

The problem with watermarking is that it's impossible to see/detect it and it's very hard to get rid of unless you know how exactly it's been done.

Comment: Thanks! So saving the camera output as PNG should be enough to get rid of any identifying metadata?

Comment: After resizing because like I said JPEG has compression artifacts which could be used to deduce your camera manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

What is your threat model and who do you want to remain anonymous towards?

For ordinary users, removing all the meta-data from a photo (such as the EXIF data) would do the job.

For advanced users capable of examining raw data for typical indicators of specific cameras/smartphones, software used to edit, etc. you need to remove the meta-data, then process the photo destructively in a common editing software such as photopea.com - rescale, apply a filter, apply auto-contrast and auto-colour-balance, etc. then save it with re-encoding.

It **may** (untested) work to scale the image down and up again using AI upscale, if you don't need to exactly retain small details.

If your threat model includes an adversary who can also trace the origin of the image, e.g. by hacking or serving warrants to whatever service you upload it to, checking their logs, tracing your IP, etc. then the easy way is to go to a nearby airport and use their public WiFi to upload it. Add VPNs to a country not on friendly terms with your adversary to make tracing more difficult. Destroy the device you used to do the upload if you are paranoid. Fly to a random foreign country and use the public Wifi there if you are beyond paranoid.